# C# - Close a child form from parent

Tags: c#, parent-child

I have a parent form and a child form.  I need to open the child form at the beginning of a method, do some pretty intensive tasks and then close the child form upon completion.

Here is basically what I've tried so far (with no luck):

Parent Form:

```
Child child = new Child();

Method()
{
    child.ShowDialog();

    //Method code here

    child.CloseScan();
}
```

Child Form:

```
public void CloseScan()
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `child.ShowDialog()`, the code will halt at that point until the dialog is closed, since you're telling it to function as a modal dialog.

If you want to have the code continue to run, you need to use `child.Show(this);` instead.  You can then do your "method code" and close the window afterwards.  (Adding "this" causes the form to be a child form of the current form...)